# Save docker state (edited postgresql.conf file for example)

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker

I have downloaded a postgresql docker image and at the moment editing some config files. The problem that I have is that whenever I edit the config files and commit the docker image (save it as a new one), it never saves anything. The image is still the same as the one I downloaded.

Image I am using:
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

I believe this is the latest docker file.
https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/a00e979002aaa80840d58a5f8cc541342e06788f/9.6/Dockerfile

This is what I did:

```
1. Run the postgresql docker container
2. Enter the terminal of the container. docker exec -i -t {id of container} /bin/bash
3. Edit some config files.
4. Exit the container.
5. Commit the changes by using docker commit {containerid} {new name}
6. Stop the old container and start the new one.
```

The new container is created. If I start the new container with the new image and check the config files I edited, my changes are not there. No changes were committed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you please provide the used mysql image? So we cen check the dockerfile. I believe in that the docker file is the reason, it calls something that overwrites your configuration changes and possible provides a better way to configure your instance as commiting lokal changes.

Comment: Hi @ReneM. I have edited my question. Please take a look. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Thanks alot, since you posted the requested informations other used it to answer your question. As I thought, your docker file prevents you from persisting your changes. he is right: @mark-oconnor

Answer (score 2):

The Docker file contains a volume declaration

https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/a00e979002aaa80840d58a5f8cc541342e06788f/9.6/Dockerfile#L52

```
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

All file edits under this path will not be saved in a Docker image commit. These data files are deliberately excluded as they define your container's state. Images on the other hand are designed to create new containers, so VOLUMEs are a mechanism to keep state separate.

It would appear that you're attempting to use Docker images as a mechanism for DB backup and recovery. This is ill-advised as the docker file system is less performant compared to the native file system typically exposed to a volume.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark rightfully points out, your data is left behind because of the volume definition, and it should not be altered for the general production use.

If you have a legitimate reason to keep the data within the image produced, you may move the postgres data from the volume by adding the following to your dockerfile:

```
 ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql/my_data
 RUN mkdir -p $PGDATA
```

I've been using this technique to produce db images for testing to speedup the feedback loop.